# Ускорить процесс сборки проекта Gradle (Android)

Tags: java, android, gradle

Хочу ускорить процесс сборки проекта `Gradle`, прочитала, что можно в  `gradle.properties` добавить строчку кода: `org.gradle.daemon=true` и проект будет собираться быстрее. На сколько я понимаю, то файл `gradle.properties` должен лежать по директории `/Users/<username>/.gradle/`, для `Mac`,  но когда я захожу по этому пути, то у меня там лежит 4 папки: caches, daemon, native, wrapper. Вопрос, где в таком случаи лежит `gradle.properties`?

Comment: положите этот файл рядом с build.gradle

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Создать текстовый файл с названием grade.properties и положить его рядом с build.gradle в проекте?

Comment: если его нет, да. Вообще, посмотрите какой нибудь проект на gradle и сверьте с тем что у вас, например этот https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Сделала, проект собирался в 2 раза дольше, чем обычно.

Comment: @Licky_girl определенно есть прогресс ))

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov Угу, 4 минуты ушло на то что бы собрать проект.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Надо просто создать там `gralde.properties` если его не существует.

Кроме того, [вышел Gradle 3.0, у которого deamon включён по умолчанию](https://docs.gradle.org/3.0/release-notes).